# iframe height external url

Tags: jquery, iframe, height

I've built a page template (in Wordpress)

```
<?php $iframe_demo_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'demo_url', true ); ?>

<div class="content">topbar content</div>

<div class="iframe">
    <iframe id="product-iframe-demo" src="<?php echo esc_url( $iframe_demo_url ); ?>" frameBorder="0" noresize="noresize"></iframe>
</div>
```

Css code to prevent double scrollbars

```
body {background:#fff;height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;overflow: hidden;}
iframe {display: block; background: #fff; border: none;width: 100%;}
```

The problem that I have is iframe *height*. I tried using `height: 100vh;` but that's not good enough.

All kinds of other jquery scripts I tried require an additional js script on the external link, so that's not possible either.

A working iframe height example is this website:
[demo example](http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/rabbit-yell-authors-rating/full_screen_preview/18971694)

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: No one? Is it really impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Simple technique to make fluid iframes without use of javascript or plugins. Using this technique we have more gains in performance and simplicity.

This is a technique of positioning a element inside of another using "position: absolute;" for the "child" and "position: relative;" for the "wrap".

```css
.fluidMedia {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* proportion value to aspect ratio 16:9 (9 / 16 = 0.5625 or 56.25%) */
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fluidMedia iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fluidMedia">
    <iframe src="http://www.bymichaellancaster.com/blog/fluid-iframe-and-images-without-javascript-plugins/" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
</div>
```